# Execute a command on a checkbox in .Net Maui

Tags: maui

I have a checkbox and this checkbox enables a border control that has date picker. To achieve this i have an observable boolean variable isEnabled, so i would like to change its value in the ViewModel, for this I have implemented Checkbox.Behaviors to execute my command when check changes. The problem i have is my command is not being executed.

`

```
 <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1">
                    <Label Text="Date To"
                           FontSize="18"
                           Padding="0,0,60,0"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name=" chkDate"
                        IsChecked="true"
                              HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                                EventName="CheckedChanged"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference chkDate},Path=State}"
                                Command="{Binding SelectDateCommand}"/>                        
                        </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                    </CheckBox>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
```

below is my Command

```
[RelayCommand]
        async Task SelectDateAsync(bool state)
        {
            try
            {
                IsEnabled = state;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Checkout", "shipto selection failed please try again or contact Khayah Cement", "OK");
            }
        }
```

Comment: checkbox does not have a `State` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with receiving an Object parameter which works:

```
[RelayCommand]
async Task SelectDateAsync(object s)
{
    try
    {
        bool state = (bool)s;
        IsEnabled = state;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         ....
    }
}
```

Also change the CommandParameter binding as FreakyAli said

```
CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference chkDate}, Path=IsChecked}"
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Liqun let me look into it

Comment: Hi Liqun Shen-MSFT my issue was resolved only that i am still new to upvote your replies, thanks a lot

Comment: Oh I see. Although you cannot upvote now, you could accept an answer (click the ✔ in the upper left corner of  answer). Go through all the answers to find which is the best one for you and accept it if you want. This will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure how your E2C behaviour is set up but that the mistake I see clearly as soon as I look at your code is that instead of sending the IsChecked property you are sending something called State, Which does not exist in CheckBox.

```
<toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
                            EventName="CheckedChanged"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference chkDate},Path=IsChecked}"
                            Command="{Binding SelectDateCommand}"/>
```

I highly recommend you look into compiled bindings so you don't face such issues again, and these issues are visible at runtime, not to mention it also optimises your code to run faster.

Comment: Thank you FrealyAli let me look into much appreciated